# How to detect ListView row click using SlideMenu

Tags: java, android

I'm using [SlideMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), I've implemented the Fragment and the ListView, what I need now is detect which row the user has clicked from the Slide Menu. How can I possibly do it?
This is the code of the listView:

```
public class listFragment extends ListFragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("menu left A", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("menu left B", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("menu left C", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("menu left D", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
    adapter.add(new SampleItem("menu left A", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

private class SampleItem {
    public String tag;
    public int iconRes;
    public SampleItem(String tag, int iconRes) {
        this.tag = tag; 
        this.iconRes = iconRes;
    }
}

public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

    public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
        title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

        return convertView;
    }

    }
  }
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ye sorry added the android tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following method without having to change my code and it worked:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Row clicked",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
```

will return the ListView object. So you can call setOnItemClickListener() method. Something like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ListView list = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     // write your click handler here
     }
});
return list;
```

Comment: The code doesn't give any error but It doesn't work, I tried to set a breakpoint inside the onItemClick but It doesn't get called when I click on a row

Comment: Rather, try adding a click listener to the View (convertView)  in getView. Any view can have a clickistener and should work without needin to implement onItemClick

Answer (score 1):

ListFragment have its own ListView by default, but it seems you are overriding default implementation with your custom function `onCreateView`. You need to be sure that this layout (`R.layout.menu`) has ListView inside and its id is set to `android.R.id.list`. Then you should be able to get a reference to that list in `onCreateView` by finding view by id or later on in any places inside your fragment by calling `ListFragment.getListView()`.

You can then:

1. override `public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` which should be called automatically for you
2. get reference to ListView and set `setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener)` on it manually (just be sure to set it after whole Layout is inflated and available for you)

If that won't work for you, you should put here also `R.layout.menu` content to help others to help you :)

best regards,

Darek

Answer (score 0):

Override the onListItemClick() for your listfragment.

```
    @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
           //here "position" is clicked item position
            }
```

Hope this will help for you.

Comment: The problem is that I can't retrieve the listView